# In Android, How can I modify a text in GridView after clicking an item?

Tags: android, gridview, text

I'm trying to put a text above the Image in grid view but i'm not able to do this.
My app will have a gridview with pictures, and when I click over the each picture, I have put the quantity of clicks above of this image in real time.

I create an Adapter and My images are appearing on my Activity.

How I can do this, on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through the onItemClickListener

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        // Create the view here
        Holder tag = new Holder();
        tag.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(textViewId);
        view.setTag(tag);
    }
    if (counts[position] == 0) {
        tag.textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else {
        tag.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tag.textView.setText("" + counts[position]);
    }
    ...
}

gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
int[] counts = new int[// item count];
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Holder tag = (Holder) view.getTag();
        if (tag != null) {
            counts[position] = counts[position] + 1;
            tag.textView.setText("" + counts[position]);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to track the count outside as a member variable.

Comment: This is not the correct way to do this. If the data changes, or the View is scrolled out of visible range (i.e. the View is recycled) your changes will be lost.

Comment: That is why you need to track the changes outside the gridview adapter in a member variable. The member variables will remain correct even if you scroll out of view.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter (or wherever appropriate to store this data depending on how long lived this click data should be), add some sort of data structure to maintain the number of clicks per position. In your adapter's getView(), you should set the text at that position according to the number of clicks you have stored in your data structure.

In your list item click listener, increment the click count in your data structure, and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your Adapter.